# Using a Kendo Grid, how do you change the wording on the "Create" button in the toolbar?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, grid, kendo-ui

I'm using a Kendo Grid I added the "create" to do an inline add of a record. How can I change the wording on the add button? Currently it reads: "Add a new Record" I want to simplify it to read just "Add" and I'd also like to keep the same Icon.

My code looks like:

```
$reports.kendoGrid(
{
    dataSource: dataSource,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    ...
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The way to do this is using the following syntax:

```
$reports.kendoGrid(
{
    dataSource: dataSource,
    toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add" }],
```

Answer (score 3):

you can find it in js and you have to chenge from there

you have to change it by the configuration this link will help you http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/ui-widgets/grid/configuration.aspx

hunted solution its perfect tally work 
in kendo.all.min.js or kendo.all.js which you are using you will find below line

```
{create:{text:"Add new record",imageClass:"k-add",className:"k-grid-add",iconClass:"k-icon"}
```

you will get the result

change it with

```
   {create:{text:"Add ",imageClass:"k-add",className:"k-grid-add",iconClass:"k-icon"}
```

Comment: :Rondey look for my edited portion after hunting i got solution for you

Comment: you have to replace not to add

Comment: its change the text to Add new Record to Add

Comment: but some time when you have to do trick you have to go out of rule or against a good practice