# How to change the "text"on the kendo grid button?

Tags: css, kendo-grid

On my kendo grid there is a button, by default it's **`add new record`**. I want to change it. I used the following tag but does not work :

```
#turbinegrid .k-icon.k-add::after {
    content: "ADD";
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the html markup of the grid and button?

Comment: by default I get this .k-icon.k-add

Comment: you want to replace the text or add it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a Kendo Grid, how do you change the wording on the "Create" button in the toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535467/using-a-kendo-grid-how-do-you-change-the-wording-on-the-create-button-in-the)

Answer (score 0):

You can set template for the button like below,

```
$("#myGrid").kendoGrid({
toolbar: [{
      template: '<div><div style="float:left;"><h2>Tech Documents</h2></div><div style="float:right;margin: 2% 1% 1% 1%;"><a title="add new" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-i-plus-outline"></span>**Create One**</a></div></div>'
     }]
});
```

Use Your Text for the button in place of **Create One**.

Answer (score 0):

When using `MVC` you can set the text like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GridViewModel>()
    .ToolBar(tools =>
    {
        tools.Create().Text("ADD");
    })
)
```

When using `jQuery` use this:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "ADD" }]
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#turbinegrid .k-icon.k-add {
    font-size: 0px !important;
}
#turbinegrid .k-icon.k-add::after {
    content: "New Text" !important;
    font-size: 18px !important;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain why this solves the problem.

Comment: This https://jsfiddle.net/1oxe4ykh/ will make you understand and if you fail to understand it, try reading `css for dummies` @NisargShah